# What is the equivalent of textScaleX and autoSizeTextType in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, mobile-development

In Android, I used textScaleX to stretch the font.  I also used autoSizeTextType to make the font's size responsive.  Any idea how to do that in Flutter?

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMinus"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="-"
    android:textScaleX="1.8"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="36sp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of packages you can use to make texts responsive to all phones such as:

https://github.com/layounisl/responsive_flutter

https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text

But in my opinion, the best option is to use ***FittedBox*** widget.
Simply just wrap your Text widget to ***FittedBox*** widget. Like I am using fittedBox in the below code to resize to the width of appbar.

```
AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    title: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth, 
        child: Text('Hey this is my long text appbar title')
    ),
),
```

This will always keep your text inside the box. Play around with the fit parameter and you'll see how it works.

Comment: Thanks, Kamrul! That helped a lot.  FittedBox will not increase the font size so I still had to set font size but at least it will keep the text inside the box if the button size gets smaller.

Comment: Cheers buddy. Good to know it helped. FittedBox has many properties, like BoxFit.scaleDown or cover or contain. Use whatever suits your need buddy.